# Share Point 2007 - Concept of an Agent?

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs

I think I already know the answer to this question, but I'm hoping I am wrong.

My background is in SQL, specifically T-SQL alongisde SSMS. I rely pretty heavily on agent jobs for periodic tasks. My question is: Is there any similar concept of an 'agent' or scheduled task in Share Point?

Specifically, I would like an email escalation period. ie, after a week of an item sitting waiting to be approved, can we have sharepoint notify someone about it? I dont think so, but I am hoping to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint has a timer job that can do task periodically: http://www.techtimepiece.com/2011/09/working-with-custom-timer-job.html

There is already some ready solutions that allow you to specify reminders for lists. Reminder is different than an alert in the sense that it doesn't need to have item altered to fire off. Reminder queries list time to time and if query returns something, it sends an email you have specified.

[Send scheduled Reminder/Alerts by email in SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32753/Send-scheduled-Reminder-Alerts-by-email-in-SharePo)

[Sharepoint Reminder Alert Feature](http://reminderalert.codeplex.com/)

Comment: See this answer for a few more alternatives - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars

Comment: This is much closer to what I needed. I'll investigate further and comment back if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look into [SharePoint 2007 Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa830816%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to accomplish those kinds of tasks.

Comment: This is true. While investigating, I dont think it has enough granular detail for everything I'm looking for, but technically speaking it does answer my question ;)

Comment: This was also very useful: http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/the-dog-ate-my-task-use-sharepoint-designer-to-email-daily-task-reminders

Comment: Yea, unfortunately MOSS and WSS don't have "agents" like that. I think you can also extend workflows in MOSS and WSS with custom workflow activities, so any edge work that needs to be done might  take place in a custom coded workflow activity...

Comment: @EtherDragon actually sharepoint has 'Scheduled jobs' called 'Timer Job'